# Custom Map tiles are blur

Tags: android, google-maps

At certain zoom levels the map tiles are blur and not doing the smooth rendering.

Using the following code:

```
public MapTileLayer setupTileLayer(final TileListener listener) {
TileProvider provider = new TileProvider() {
        @Override
        public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            String filename = listener.loadTileFilename(x, y, zoom, true);
            if (filename != null && filename.trim().length() > 0) {
                byte[] bytes = FileService.getBytesForFile(filename);
                if (bytes != null) {
                    return new Tile(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, bytes);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    TileOverlayOptions options = new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(provider);
    options.visible(true);

    return new GoogleTileLayer(map.addTileOverlay(options));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 512x512 instead of 256x256 fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

maybe an image of what is the problem could help, but anyway you should take care about the size of tiles.
On most of the devices the size of the tiles (or how gmaps tiles the world) is 256x256 px, but on devices with higher density (I had experience with a Nexus 10), the size of tiles is 512x512. It means that if you have/download a tile that is 256 and show at 512 it decreases quality.
Look at here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay#coordinates

> When creating images for a tile layer, you will need to create an
>   image for each tile at each zoom level that you wish to support.
>   Google Maps targets 256 dp (device-independent pixels) when displaying
>   tiles. For high resolution devices, it is recommended that you return
>   high dpi tiles (512x512 px). Refer to the Android Developers
>   documentation for information on supporting different screen sizes and
>   densities.

If you are using an URLTileProvider you can give the size in the constructor, if you are using custom created tiles you should either create 2 version of the tiles (for normal/high densities), or simply create high densities and let the system do the downscaling for normal devices.

If the problem is not this, please attach a picture of your issue!

Comment: why a downvote? and why the author answers and accepts his own post when I wrote a more complete version (before him) explaining the very same thing?
That's funny, whoever downvoted